# Remove mask circle from image using Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

**i'm trying to remove the center of image using the BitWish_not but's the result is not good. see it below.**

[image: worning mask]

As you see, it didn’t remove all the colors

Below my code

```
image = cv2.imread("icons/agta.jpg")
height,width,depth = image.shape
circle = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(circle,(int(width/2),int(height/2)),90,1,thickness=-1)

masked = cv2.bitwise_not(image, image, mask=circle)

cv2.imshow("masked", masked)
cv2.imwrite("hue.jpg",masked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand your expectations but can't you simply draw circle directly on image ?

Comment: I need change the radius of the circle image

Comment: But' i will try creating an white circle and remove it after

Comment: I do not understand the problem. What is the input and what is your desired output? What do you want in place of the white circle? Making it black should be easy.

Comment: The input is the image without circle, i need to create a mask alfa circle in image using circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem, here is one way to do it in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Apply morphology to clean it as a mask
- Invert mask and make 3 channel
- Apply mask to input to make circle black
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('white_circle.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold input image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology open and close and dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (55,55))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# invert mask
mask = 255 -mask

# make mask 3 channel
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply mask to image to blacken circle area
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('white_circle_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('white_circle_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('white_circle_masked.jpg', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Blackened circle in input:

[image]

Comment: It wasn't exactly that, but it works perfectly.
Thanks for help me and sorry my bad english